# Table not updating when datasource is updated

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tab-Bar Controller + UINavigation Controller app.
In tabs 1,2,3 I have table views that offer the user some items to choose from. Once the user selects the items they get added to a Cart.
Tab 4 is a table that shows the items in Cart.

I noticed that when the user selects items in tabs 1 or 2 or 3 they show ip in the cart tab the forst time its clicked on.

If the user then goes back to tabs 1,2,3 and selects more items, the table in the "Cart" tab does not get updated.

Im  not sure why this is the case. I have programmed in the "Cell for Row @ IndexPath" method to get data from the Datasource each time this method is called.

Im puzzled. Wondering if there is something obvious that Im missing here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the data source for the table in tab 4 have the updated items? Is the problem in both the model and the view, or just the view?

Comment: Yes, you really do need to go accept any answers that have helped you. I'm feeling generous tonight, but it will get harder and harder to get answers to your questions unless you take a moment to show your appreciation for the free help you're getting.

Comment: These appear to be answers that helped you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413130/how-to-put-a-property-list-in-the-documents-folder-of-my-app-when-app-is-shipped  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333011/confused-about-how-to-update-my-datasources-on-my-uitableview-after-app-has-been  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369159/fetching-a-file-from-a-url-for-mobile-app-how-to-manage-server-side-running-joom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table only updates its data in two situations.

1. You're using an 'NSFetchedResultsController' to bridge the gap from your data to the view. This controller automatically updates the view whenever the underlying data changes (and, similarly, automatically updates the data when it receives an add/edit/delete request from the view).
2. You handle it all manually in your own code, most importantly calling the `UITableView`'s `reloadData` method after the data in the datasource has changed.

Comment: Ahh. I see how accept works. Sorry if I didn't accept before. Im just starting with these online forums

Comment: Yes, thats what I was missing. the reload data method. I wasn't doing that. I'll try this approach. Thanks

Comment: Quick question. I looked up NSFetchedResultsController and it looks like one can only use this with Core Data. Im not using core data. Im persisting my data in the model object that handles the tableview. Basically Im adding my selections to an array within the model object. Then Im just using that array to get the data to populate my tab 4 view.  Also, where do I put [tableview reloaddata] in View did load or somewhere else?

Comment: @user657514 viewWillAppear is a better place because viewDidLoad only gets called when the view has to be built from scratch, which only happens when it's first created and when the system has dumped the view due to memory constraints and it's later displayed. viewWillAppear is called, as the name implies, every time the view will appear. However, it would be even better if you kept track of whether it needed calling, something like a flag to indicate that the view is out of date: reloadData can be very cpu intensive if the table is at all large or complex. Reload in willAppear only if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reload the data in the table view friend .

[yourtable reloaddata];

use this where you want to show your data